# Is there a word for someone who is not aware of how pretty or handsome he/she is?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idioms

Is there a word or an idiom that describes someone who is beautiful but unaware of it?

Comment: Humble and Modest.

Comment: How, in this context, are you defining "beauty"?

Comment: Does the specific "unacknowledged asset" have to be ***beauty**?* What about people who are *funny, wise, kind, likeable,* etc., but not aware of their exalted status in the eyes of others?

Comment: Hidden gem, diamond-in-the-rough, radiant

Comment: ***Unaware*** ?

Comment: oblivious, simple, naive, child-like, ingenuous...

Comment: @Mari-LouA is on the right track (+1). Others, leaning toward modest, humble, etc. are off track. Ignorance of a strength does not imply humility wrt it.

Comment: Look up synonyms for "naive".

Comment: The term ingénue may be useful to you - it specifically refers to a young and innocent woman, but generally has the connotation of beauty, eagerness, etc which are untempered by worldliness.

Answer (score 7):

*[Innocent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/innocent)* might work to capture the lack of conceit:

> adjective
>
> Without experience or knowledge of:
>
> *ODO*

*Alice is that much more charming, because she is so **innocent** of her beauty.*

Answer (score 4):

"modest", as mentioned by Kandpal in a comment, is the closest I can get.

Other adjectives such as "humble", "shy", "meek" and "timid" seem like poorer choices.

- That country girl is really **modest**. She seems to be **completely unaware of her beauty.**

> - modest - (adj) "not too proud or confident about yourself or your abilities"
> - modesty - (noun) " the quality of not being too proud or confident about yourself or your abilities" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/modest)

e.g.

"I noticed she is very modest about her physical characteristics."

"The scientist accepted the prize with modesty."

"The princess is known for her modesty, which is very unusual among royals."

"His whole speech reeks of false modesty."

Comment: IMHO, modesty and humility are not implied by ignorance. Perhaps if she were aware of her beauty you might see that she is not modest at all. Completely unrelated, IMO, except that someone who is immodest might be less likely to be ignorant of her beauty. The converse does not follow (ignorance does not imply modesty).

Answer (score 3):

In our civilization, where physical beauty is so highly prized, I would call someone who isn't aware of their own good looks to be [***clueless***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clueless).

Comment: Please include attributions for all links in plain text (i.e., M-W) somewhere in you posts.

Answer (score 1):

> <sup>If the person lacks self-awareness of their good looks, then [Mari-Lou A's suggestions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245655/is-there-a-word-for-someone-who-is-not-aware-of-how-pretty-or-handsome-he-she-is/245685#comment532020_245655) are pretty spot on.</sup>

If the person is  trying to succeed by the merit of their work rather than their looks, then you could use the word ***unpretentious***.

> : not having or showing the unpleasant quality of people who want to be regarded as more impressive, successful, or important than they really are
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unpretentious)</sub>

However, if the person lacks confidence in the way they look, then I would use the word ***insecure***.

> :  not confident or sure :  uncertain <feeling somewhat insecure of his reception>
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insecure)</sub>