# Another word for "understated sexuality"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am trying to find a proper word for describing a visual concept.

At the moment the closest description is "understated sexuality", but maybe there is another word to describe a woman that is beautiful, attractive, sexy, confident and at the same time modest?

"Majestic or glorious" ([Eilia 2015](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246283/another-word-for-understated-sexuality#comment533497_246283)) "are too lavish, I need something different." ([maxlaks 2015](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246283/another-word-for-understated-sexuality#comment533528_246283))

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245655/is-there-a-word-for-someone-who-is-not-aware-of-how-pretty-or-handsome-he-she-is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't throw a bunch of adjectives together and expect English to cough up some magic word. It might happen, but then again, it might not.

If you want to focus on her beauty, use

> beautiful, attractive, appealing, charming

If you want to focus on her appearance, you could try

> classy, elegant, sophisticated... or even [resplendent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/resplendent) (depending on the case)

For confidence, try

> [poised](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/poised), [self-assured](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self-assured)

Modesty, in some senses, goes against confidence, but you can use

> [self-effacing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self-effacing), [unpretentious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unpretentious)

---

For understated sexuality in particular, I'm partial to

**[elegant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/elegant)**

> (of people or their behaviour) attractive and showing a good sense of style

or, in extreme cases

**[sensuous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sensuous#sensuous__3)**

> Attractive or gratifying physically, especially sexually:

<sub>[Oxford]</sub>

---

PS - In my humble opinion as a reader, I like writers to describe girls with as many specific adjectives as possible, rather than be too laconic about it. Even your description in the post would mean more to a girl than any single word could.

Answer (score 13):

How about [winsome](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/winsome):

> adj.
>
> Attractive or appealing in a fresh, innocent way

Comment: Very good suggestion, but does this term carry also the connotation of *being sexy*?

Comment: And does it also suggest *confidence*? Winsomeness is often found holding hands with shyness.

Comment: When I think of women I would describe as winsome, I may not think of them as being "sexy" per se, but certainly very attractive.  Bear in mind too, "sexy" can mean many things to many people.

Answer (score 6):

I like *[chic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chic)*:

> adjective (chicer, chicest)
>
> Elegantly and stylishly fashionable:

The connotation of *stylish* welcomes a deeper appreciation than most people offer to the elegant woman the OP describes:

> 1856, as a noun, "*style*, *artistic* *skill*,"
>   from French *chic*, 19c. in
>   "*stylishness*" sense, originally "*subtlety*" (16c.), which is of unknown
>   origin, perhaps [Klein] related to German *Schick* "*tact*, *skill*,"
>   from
>   Middle Low German *schikken* "*arrange* *appropriately*," or
>   Middle High
>   German *schicken* "to *arrange*, set in order;"...
>
> *[Etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=chic&searchmode=none)*

Answer (score 2):

Winsome is a good old English word for that:

adjective
1.
sweetly or innocently charming; winning; engaging:
a winsome smile.

an elegant demure and a winsome smile describes many a lass in English books.

Comment: Hi John, welcome to ELU! _Winsome_ is a pretty fitting word. Could you provide the source of the definition you gave?

Comment: I'm no longer sure of the source.... I generally use Cambridge or Oxford dictionaries. Next time I'll cite the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Someone fitting exactly that description (yeah, she’s currently reading over my shoulder) seems to find a way to fascinate me every day, so it might just be that all those qualities add up to make her “[fascinating](https://www.google.com/search?q=facinating&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).”

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the person has a wholesome beauty.

Answer (score 0):

[Ravishing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Ravishing?s=t)

1.) Extremely beautiful or attractive; enchanting; entrancing.